# undefined reference to 'memset' when used makefile in linux

Tags: c, linux, makefile

my environment as followed:
linux version: 3.10.0-1160.2.2.el7.centos.plus.i686; make version is 3.82 ; gcc version is 4.8.5;

I just created a main.c file which as followed:

```
int main (int a)
{

  memset(c,3,7);
  return 0;
}
```

when I used the order: gcc main.c -o main.o,

I only get a warning: incompatile implicit declaration of built-in function'memset'[enabled by default]

when I used the order: gcc -M main.c -o main.o, no warining or error message

but when I used the makefile to make , there is an error: undefined reference to memset

the makefile as followed:

```
SOURCES=main.o

CFLAGS=-nostdlib -nostdinc -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector

LDFLAGS=-Tlink.ld

ASFLAGS=-felf

all: $(SOURCES) link

clean:

    -rm *.o kernel

link:

    ld $(LDFLAGS) -o kernel $(SOURCES)

.s.o:

     nasm $(ASFLAGS) $<
```

my question is what I should do to let this makefile work properly.

Note: As I googled, suppose no need to include string.h, but when I include, still got the error message when I used this makefile

Comment: You need to include the header file for `memset`.

Comment: `#include <string.h>` in main.c

Comment: `memset` is part of the standard C library. If you build with `-nostdlib -nostdinc -fno-builtin` the standard library will not be available. Since you try to create your own kernel, you have to create your own set of standard C functions.

Comment: I add header file like <string.h> or <linux/string.h>, but seems like it does not work as expected. Meanwhile supposed the order 'make' should find the headfile automatically

Comment: "As I googled, suppose no need to include string.h" You googled up a lie.

Comment: You don't even need a Makefile. Without a Makefile, `make main` should work.

Comment: Do you know what `-nostdlib` means? Why are you using it?

Comment: I think you need to explain why you use those variables (`CFLAGS` etc.) in the Makefile.

Comment: If you tell the compiler not to use standard library (`-nostdlib`) *and* not to use builtins (`-fno-builtin`) *and* you do not provide a replacement for both versions of `memset` your compiler runs out of options... It can't do its job if you take away all the necessary tools

Comment: Where did you get the idea to use `-M` option? Did you read what it does? Besides other things you can find this in the [spec](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html): "Passing -M to the driver implies -E, and suppresses warnings with an implicit -w." and `-E` means: "Stop after the preprocessing stage; do not run the compiler proper.". In the end: No compilation at all and suppress all warnings.

Comment: You should be getting an error about `c` not being a defined variable.

Comment: Why do I get the feeling that you're asking about a homework assignment where the Makefile was provided by the instructor?

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: this is not a homework. And thank you guys for the input!  The problem is solved. I need to define a memset definiton myself with the -nostdlib.